# How to use tf.losses.log_loss in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

What is the input of tf.losses.log_loss ?

```
cross_entropy = tf.losses.log_loss(labels, predictions)
```

Anybody can show me some examples about it ?
Official guide has no examples .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an estimator:

```
m = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    model_dir=model_dir,
    feature_columns=base_columns,
    hidden_units=[1024,512,256,128,64,32])
```

Train your model:

```
m.train(
    input_fn=input_fn('numerai_training_data.csv', num_epochs=4, shuffle=True),
    steps=1000)
```

Run your predictions and get labels from the test data set:

```
predictionTest = m.predict(input_fn=input_predict_fn('numerai_tournament_data_test.csv', shuffle=False))
labels = getLabels('numerai_tournament_data_test.csv')
predicted_classes = [p["classes"] for p in predictionTest]
```

Run your log_loss:

```
 tf.losses.log_loss(predicted_classes,labels,weights=1.0,scope=None, epsilon=1e-07,loss_collection=tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES,reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.SUM_BY_NONZERO_WEIGHTS)
 losses=tf.losses.get_losses(scope=None,loss_collection=tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES)
```

Unless you're also competing in numerai, in which case disregard this answer.